# LINQ to Entites and ObjectQuery

Tags: linq-to-entities, objectquery

I have Person entity which has a 1 : N relationship with `Person_Addresses` (fields: `PersonID`, `AddressID`, `ValidFrom`). I want to get all `Person` records and associated `Person_Addresses` with only latest ValidFrom. How should I do this using ObjectQuery or IQueryable?

**Edit:**
I mentioned `ObjectQuery` and `IQueryable`, because I wanted to have a solution using extension methods (I think, that how it's called). Also I forgot to mention that I'm using [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) where I have the entities generated. I want to get a person object which has it's person_adress member eagerly loaded.

Here are the entities structure:
Person members: int id, string firstname, string lastname, Partner_Address partneradress

Person_Address members: `int personid`, `int adressid`, `date validfrom`

Comment: Looks complicated but should it be? The generated SQL should look like this:
SELECT [Id]
      ,[Firstname]
      ,[Lastname]
      ,prt.AdressID
FROM [Person] p
CROSS APPLY 
( SELECT TOP(1) [PersonId],[AdressId],[ValidFrom]
 FROM [Person_Addresses] pa
 WHERE p.[Id] = pa.[PersonId]
 ORDER BY [ValidFrom] DESC
) prt

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

I have the following entities.

```
    //Person Entity
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID  { get; set; }
        public string PersonName { get; set; }
    }

    //PersonAddress Entity
    public class PersonAddress
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    }
```

Then fire the following query.

```
    //Get the latest ValidFrom for each person from PersonAddress.
    var getLatestDateRecords =
    from p in lstPersonAddress
    group p by p.PersonID into g
    select new
    {
        Infos =
            (from PA in g
            select new
            {
                PersonId = PA.PersonID
                Date = g.Max(t=>t.ValidFrom)
            }).Distinct()
    };

    //Segregate the ValidFroms and PersonId from the
    //previous record set(getLatestDateRecords).
    var segRecords =
        from x in getLatestDateRecords
        from y in x.Infos
        select new { Date = y.Date, PersonId = y.PersonId };

    //Obtain all the relevant information from the PersonAddress
    // for the latest ValidFrom dates.
    var allValidRecords =
        from PA in lstPersonAddress
        join x in segRecords
        on PA.ValidFrom equals x.Date
        where PA.PersonID == x.PersonId
        select new {
                PersonId = PA.PersonID
                , AddressId = PA.AddressID
                , Date = PA.ValidFrom
            };

    //Get the final result
    var resultSet =
        from p in lstPerson
        join x in allValidRecords
        on p.PersonID equals x.PersonId
        select new
        {
            PersonId = p.PersonID
            ,PersonName = p.PersonName
            ,AddressId = x.AddressId,
            Date = x.Date
        };
```

I found it to be working fine with some test data.

Let me know in case of any concern.

Comment: Well I think that you got the idea as how I did that. I don't think that it will be a problem for you to suit your requirement. You can take a look into the Entites upon which I have fired the Linq. It looks very similar that of yours. Hope you can proceed further without much hassel. All the best

Comment: Hi, this is a tested program. You can even go ahead with some sample. And more over, it has been done into pieces for the sake of understanding.

Comment: I happened to come accros this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods/584836#584836

I wonder if it's possible to join 2 different querys using groupjoin? something like: PersonQuery.GroupJoin(... PersonAddressQuery ...)