# left join using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

I have tableA and tableB.
I would like to perform left join using lambda expression. This is the equal sql statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
    LEFT JOIN tableB B ON A.userId=B.userId
```

How can I do that using lambda expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's usually an error to use an explicit `join` in LINQ to Entities.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/)

Instead, use the navigation properties:

```
var q = Context.TableAs.Select(a => new { a.Foo, a.TableB.Bar });
```

LINQ to Entities will coalesce null references. So if `a.TableB` is `null` for some record in `TableAs`, then `a.TableB.Bar` will return `null` instead of giving you a null reference exception. So it behaves like a SQL `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Naor: Usually, the right thing to do is to add them. You should use explicit `joins` mostly only if you *can't* add them for some reason.

Comment: @Naor: Like I said, mostly, you don't. You haven't yet convinced me that you have a good reason to omit navigations. Navigations are *the right way* to relate entities.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: What about the desire to learn? How can I do left joins in lambda syntax?

Comment: @Naor: That's a different question. You asked how to do it with L2E. The *right* way to do it in L2E is to use navigations. You want to do it in L2O, then you can use `Join()` with a `DefaultIfEmpty()` on the "right" sequence. But don't do that for L2E, normally.

Comment: I have inherited a db that joins several tables without using any keys. (Before anyone weighs in with comments about that - I already know and as soon as I can replace the POS I will, but atm I can't.) And I can't create Navigations without them, so I have to do joins in code, and my personal preference is to use Lambda, in C# it makes more sense to me.