# dynamically build “FULL OUTER JOIN” for “ Dynamic Mutiple Columns” LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq

I have used  below link to get Left Outer Join [How do I do a left outer join with Dynamic Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364436/how-do-i-do-a-left-outer-join-with-dynamic-linq). Could any one help me in creating dynamicaly buid "FULL OUTER JOIN" for "Dynamic Multiple Columns" LINQ TO SQL.