# Linq to SQL equivalent of this query

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

This is the query that I'm trying to reproduce:

```
select
    act.AccountID,
    ast.AssetID,
    b.Amount
from
    Account act left outer join
    Balance b on act.AccountID = b.AccountID left outer join
    Asset ast on b.AssetID = ast.AssetID
```

I'm trying to get the results as the following:

```
Dictionary(of Account, Dictionary(of Asset, Double))
```

Comment: Left outer join in LINQ-to-SQL (c#): http://stackoverflow.com/q/584820/284240

Comment: That doesn't get me the type of result that I need.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, the left joins are done with simple from statements in the LINQ 2 SQL syntax

```
Dim dc as new myDataContext
Dim result = from act in dc.Accounts
         from b in dc.Balance
         from ast in dc.Asset
         select act.AccountID, ast.AssetID, b.Amount
```

Comment: how does that include the join column AccountID?