# left outer join in lambda/method syntax in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)

I can't find a left outer join example of Linq lambda (with extension methods), at least, not a clear one.

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Parent
{
    PID     // PK
}

Child
{
    CID     // PK
    PID     // FK
    Text
}
```

I want to join Parent with Child, and for every child missing, I want the default value for Text to be "[[Empty]]". How can I do this with linq lambda syntax?

I currently have the following:

```
var source = lParent.GroupJoin(
    lChild,
    p => p.PID,
    c => c.PID,
    (p, g) =>
        new // ParentChildJoined
        {
            PID = p.PID;
            // How do I add child values here?
        });
```

Comment: What have you already tried? And what do you mean by "linq lambda"?

Comment: I cannot understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: @mellamokm oh very helpful, all those examples are in lambda syntax! oh wait, no they're not. -_-

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I mean how to do it with extension methods. :P

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You're close. The following will select `PID`, `CID` and `Text` for each child, and `PID`, `CID = -1` and `Text = "[[Empty]]"` for each parent with no children:

```
var source = lParent.GroupJoin(
    lChild,
    p => p.PID,
    c => c.PID,
    (p, g) => g
        .Select(c => new { PID = p.PID, CID = c.CID, Text = c.Text })
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new { PID = p.PID, CID = -1, Text = "[[Empty]]" }))
    .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.PID equals c.PID into g
from c in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
{
   p.PID,
   CID = c != null ? (int?)c.CID : null, // Could be null
   Text = c != null ? c.Text : "[[Empty]]"
}
```

With lambda:

```
class ChildResult
{
   public int PID { get; set; }
   public int? CID { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}

lParent.SelectMany(p => p.Childs.Any() ?
  p.Childs.Select(c => new ChildResult() { PID = c.PID, CID = c.CID, Text = c.Text }) :
  new [] { new ChildResult() { PID = p.PID, CID = null, Text = "[[Empty]]" } } );
```