# Left outer join errors

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get this left outer join working, but I seem to be encountering some issues. I have taken the example code from the [MSDN left join article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx). This example is in LINQ syntax, but I want mine in extension method syntax, so I have also referenced this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods) question.

```
Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

// Create two lists.
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

var query = people
            .GroupJoin(pets,
            p1 => p1.FirstName,
            p2 => p2.Owner.FirstName,
            (p1, p2) => new {p1,p2})
            .SelectMany(x => x.p2.DefaultIfEmpty(),
             (x, y) => new { FirstName = x.p1.FirstName, PetName = y.Name });

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
        }
```

My query is basically identical to the code I referenced, but I am getting this error:

```
NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This should be extremely simple. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Query syntax is much easier to read. But to answer your question, before you access a property in the object (from the left join) you have to check it for `null`. (When using Linq2Sql this is however not needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing that part of sample query:

```
PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name)
```

On your query it's just `PetName = y.Name`, so whenever there is no corresponding row in `pets` list you're getting `NullReferrenceException` because `y` is `null`.

Should be:

```
var query = people
            .GroupJoin(pets,
            p1 => p1.FirstName,
            p2 => p2.Owner.FirstName,
            (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 })
            .SelectMany(x => x.p2.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (x, y) => new { FirstName = x.p1.FirstName, PetName = (y == null ? String.Empty : y.Name) });
```

Or you can use `DefaultIdEmpty(TSource)` method overload:

```
var def = new Pet { Name = string.Empty };

var query = people
            .GroupJoin(pets,
            p1 => p1.FirstName,
            p2 => p2.Owner.FirstName,
            (p1, p2) => new { p1, p2 })
            .SelectMany(x => x.p2.DefaultIfEmpty(def),
                (x, y) => new { FirstName = x.p1.FirstName, PetName = y.Name });
```

Comment: That works, but I thought that was the purpose of `DefaultIfEmpty`. Doesn't that take care of the cases where the right hand collection contains null values?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` returns default value where collection is empty (e.g. there is no corresponding values in joined collection). For all reference types it's `null`. That's how `LEFT JOIN` works.

Comment: So since I know `DefaultIfEmpty` has an overload where I can specify an object to use, it should be possible to create a `Pet` object: `Pet defaultPet = new Pet { Name = "" };` and use `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultPet) right?` In this case, I would not need to check for null values in my `SelectMany`.