# LINQ LEFT JOIN not working on NULL values

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables **Student** and **Marks**.

**Student** table have the following fields:
 `StudentID`,`Name`,`MarkID(Nullable)`.
**Marks** table have the following fields:
`MarkID`,`Mark`

> Student table

```
StudentID   Name    MarkID

1           Mark    1 

2           Mike    NULL

3           John    NULL

4           Paul    2
```

> **Mark table**

```
MarkID  Mark

1       80

2       100
```

If I use the left join then  i getting only `mark` and `paul` records.
I want all the records in the left table(`Student`)
My Query is:

```
   var query = (from s in Students  
               join m in Marks on s.MarkID equals m.MarkID 
               into mar from subMark in mar.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where(m.Mark > 80)
               Select s.Name)
               .ToList()
```

Note: It is an Example only.
While joining two tables using left join and applying where condition on the second table ,If joined column value is null in first table,it won't bring the record from first table.

Comment: I'm confused, if you're just selecting student names why are you joining in the first place?

Comment: @mattytommo: i guess it's just a test.

Comment: @mattytommo: it is an example only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is we  use the where clause in Left join.So it will discard the null value records.

```
var sampleQuery= (from f in food 
            join j in juice on f.ID equals j.ID into juiceDetails from juice in juiceDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where(!j.deleted)
            join fr in fruit on f.ID equals fr.ID into fruitDetails from fruit in fruitDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where(!fr.deleted)
            select new
            {
            // codes

            });
```

Instead of this we have to check the where clause in table itself.Like this

```
var sampleQuery= (from f in food 
            join j in juice.Table().where(x=>!x.deleted) on f.ID equals j.ID into juiceDetails from juice in juiceDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()              
            join fr in fruit.Table().where(x=>!x.deleted) on f.ID equals fr.ID into fruitDetails from fruit in fruitDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()                
            select new
            {
            // codes

            });
```

It will work fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

NULL comparisons are **always** false. That's the way SQL's three-valued logic works. If you want to match rows where the values are both null you should use a statement that checks both of them for null.

In a SQL statement you would write:

```
ON S.MARKID=M.MARKID OR (S.MARKID IS NULL AND M.MARKID IS NULL)
```

In C# you can use the comparison operator and your LINQ provider will convert this to `IS NULL`, eg:

```
on s.MarkID == m.MarkID || (s.MarkID == null && m.MarkID==null)
```

Comment: Sir how to check it in LINQ in C#

Comment: In C# just compare the value to null eg `S.MARKID==null`. EF or LINQ-to-SQL will convert this to `IS NULL`.

Comment: This really works. It gets translated as most of us are used to do with optional parameters in SQL. The only thing is: If, for instance MarkID is an int, the Intellisense will complain and generate a warning because the expression will always be false, though it generates the correct SQL. Not sure how to "workaround" that.

Comment: @jpgrassi simply don't use an int. Otherwise any query that *does* return a NULL for that int property will throw an exception. `int` in C# is the equivalent of `INT NOT NULL` in SQL. Also note that outer joins can return nulls for missing records

Comment: I just ran a test here. I have two tables. Restaurant and Poll. In the poll table I have an int column that holds the week number of that poll. If I want to select all restaurants and bring how many votes each have I need a left join with the Poll table. But, I need to filter to bring only votes for the current week, and of course consider restaurants that didn't had any votes. What I did was: (x.WeekNumber == weekNum || x.WeekNumber == null). For my surprise it worked.

Answer (score 3):

/EDIT: My first answer was using a FULL OUTER JOIN. this was way over the top and probably wrong or not compleltly correct.

The new answer uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN. I have created some sample data using LinqPad to get a working example. Ignore the `.Dump()` method if you are not using LinqPad.

```
var Students = new List<Student>() {
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="John", MarkId = 1},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Paul", MarkId = 1},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Steve", MarkId = 1},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="John", MarkId = 2},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Paul", MarkId = 3},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Steve", MarkId = 1},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Paul", MarkId = 3},
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="John"  },
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="Steve"  },
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, Name ="John", MarkId = 1}
        
    };
    
    var Marks = new List<Mark>() {
        new Mark() {MarkId = 1, Value = 60},
        new Mark() {MarkId = 2, Value = 80},
        new Mark() {MarkId = 3, Value = 100}
    };
    
    var StudentMarks = Students
                        .GroupJoin(
                            Marks,
                            st => st.MarkId,
                            mk => mk.MarkId,
                            (x,y) => new {
                                            StudentId = x.StudentId, 
                                            Name = x.Name,
                                            Mark = y.Select (z => z.Value).SingleOrDefault()
                                          }
                        )
                        .Dump();

    
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
}

public class Mark
{
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

[image]

As you cann see in my Students list, there a 2 students without a MarkId. Those 2 get the default value assigned due to `.SingleOrDefault()`. I think this will solve your problem and gives you a good basis for further fiddeling.

references:
[How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)

Comment: thank you. it will work fine .consider  both that table has Deleted Flag.I want  to check the Deleted Flag Condition (before "select new", using Where clause ).It did not bring the full records.It skips the records that containing NULL value.How to resolve this issue??(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: Give me a second, I will edit my answer to give you a solution with a "simple" GroupJoin. I wasn't satisfied with my answer either.

Comment: I want to check the Delete Flag in Where Clause.

Comment: Neither you're student table, nor your mark table do have a delete flag. what are you talking about?

Comment: I want to check the deleted flag condition for both table...consider an situation both the table have the deleted flag..how to apply the where clause before selecting the value .if I put the where condition means full records did not come..hope u understand.

Comment: No sorry, I don't. I do not know what you mean with "deleted flag"

Comment: Consider an Situation both the tables have the one more column named as "Deleted"(Bool type).i want the records that have the False in that Deleted Column.(normal deleted record Checking Condition)

Comment: Why didn't you say so in your question. This is a different matter altogether, because you either want the deleted flag vom student, from mark, or you want to join on them. 
I suggest you ask another question on this topic

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have written `From` in your Join statement while joining it.
Instead you should use `in`::

```
   from s in Students  
    join m in Marks on s.MarkID equals m.ID into mar
    from subMark in mar.DefaultIfEmpty()
    Select s.Name).ToList()
```

Comment: I think that's probably a pasting error on his part. Good spot though.

Comment: @Rahul:ya i forget that.It is an example only.my doubt is when joining two table,if the left table  containg Null values in forgein key field.at that time the null value containg record didnot come.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This solution only works if you have at least one row in subMark. The rows' ID doesn't matter.

```
var query = (from s in Students  
               join m in Marks on s.MarkID equals m.MarkID into fullM
               into mar from subMark in mar.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where(m.Mark > 80)
               Select s.Name)
               .ToList()
```

the keyword **into** does the magic. Adding it shows all rows, also those, which have NULL-Values in mar.