# Performing 1-to-1 Left Outer Join in LINQ using Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda, left-join

I have the below LINQ query:

```
dbContext.NAVSummaries
        .Join(dbContext.NAVSummaries.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                current => new
                {
                    current.Portfolio,
                    PD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate) == 2 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -3).Value :
                            SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate) == 1 ? DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -2).Value :
                                                                                DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, -1).Value
                },
                previous => previous == null ? null : new { previous.Portfolio, PD = previous.ValueDate },
                (outer, inner) => new { outer, inner }
        )
        .Where(n => !dateStart.HasValue || n.outer.ValueDate.CompareTo(dateStart.Value) >= 0)
        .Where(n => !dateEnd.HasValue || n.outer.ValueDate.CompareTo(dateEnd.Value) <= 0)
```

There are x number of records for a given ValueDate, and x-1 number of records on it's previous business date. The NAVSummaries DbSet is self-joined on the ValueDate column with the ValueDate item matching its previous business date. However, the output results a count of only x-1. I wish to perform a left-outer join so that all the x records of the left table/collection are returned.

**EDIT:** There will be only one record/item matching to the previous business date. So it has to be kind of One-To-One mapping.

NavSummary Entity :

```
public class NAVSummary
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public string Portfolio { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public DateTime ValueDate { get; set; }
        public decimal BackOfficeNAV { get; set; }
        public decimal FrontOfficeNAV { get; set; }
        public decimal DifferencePercent { get; set; }
        public decimal Threshold { get; set; }
        public int ExtractId { get; set; }
        public string ExtractStatus { get; set; }
        public string PortfolioOwner { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTimeModified { get; set; }
        public int MostCorrectNAV { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<NAVComment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<NAVStatus> Statuses { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<NAVExtract> Extracts { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsChange { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal DayOverDayChange { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [NotMapped]
        public DateTime PreviousValueDate { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal PreviousDP { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the classes?

Comment: @LucianBumb, added the NavSummary entity class

Comment: it is a bit confusing, why you are trying to do with LEFT JOIN, inside of an entity, can you show how you want the result of this query?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with complex queries including joins, group by etc., I would suggest you using the LINQ query syntax for most of the parts, since it's more natural and readable due to transparent identifiers and `let` expressions. The different type joins are described here [join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Here is your query using the query syntax:

```
var query =
    from current in db.NAVSummaries
    let currentWD = SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw", current.ValueDate)
    let currentPD = DbFunctions.AddDays(current.ValueDate, currentWD == 2 ? -3 : currentWD == 1 ? -2 : -1).Value
    join previous in db.NAVSummaries
    on new { current.Portfolio, PD = currentPD }
    equals new { previous.Portfolio, PD = previous.ValueDate }
    into previousGroup
    from previous in previousGroup.DefaultIfEmpty() // LEFT OUTER JOIN
    select new { outer = current, inner = previous };
if (dateStart.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate >= dateStart.Value);
if (dateEnd.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(e => e.outer.ValueDate <= dateEnd.Value);
```

Comment: thanks for rewriting the query for me. that worked :)