# LEFT JOIN with LINQ produces NULL reference exception

Tags: c#, linq, join, left-join

I am trying to convert current code using JOIN to the LEFT JOIN using LINQ. This is the current code

```html
globalFunctions = _rolesAdapter.GetSecurityRightsForRole(SysManagerConstants.GLOBAL_DEFAULTS_ROLE_NUMBER, "SecFunc").
                Select(secRight => new FuncViewModel()
                {
                    Descrip = secRight.SecFunc.Descrip,
                    FuncCode = secRight.SecFunc.FuncCode,
                    Grouping = secRight.SecFunc.Grouping,
                    Progmodule = secRight.SecFunc.Progmodule,
                    SubCat = secRight.SecFunc.SubCat,
                    GrantPerm = secRight.GrantPerm
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Descrip);

            //Unassigned
            editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions = editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions.Join(globalFunctions, uf => uf.FuncCode, gf => gf.FuncCode,
                    (uf, gf) => new FuncViewModel()
                    {
                        Descrip = uf.Descrip,
                        FuncCode = uf.FuncCode,
                        Grouping = uf.Grouping,
                        Progmodule = uf.Progmodule,
                        SubCat = uf.SubCat,
                        GrantPerm = (byte)(gf.GrantPerm | uf.GrantPerm),
                        DefaultGrantPerm = gf.GrantPerm
                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Descrip);
```

My attempt to convert into LEFT JOIN based on the 
[How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)

```html
//Unassigned
            editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions = editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions.GroupJoin(globalFunctions, 
                uf => uf.FuncCode, gf => gf.FuncCode,
                    (uf, gf) => new FuncViewModel()
                    {
                        Descrip = uf.Descrip,
                        FuncCode = uf.FuncCode,
                        Grouping = uf.Grouping,
                        Progmodule = uf.Progmodule,
                        SubCat = uf.SubCat,
                        GrantPerm = (byte)(((int?)gf.FirstOrDefault().GrantPerm??1) | uf.GrantPerm),
                        DefaultGrantPerm = (byte) ((int?)gf.FirstOrDefault().GrantPerm ?? 1)
                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Descrip);
```

I tried SingleOrDefault and FirstOrDefault and I keep getting the NULL object reference in run-time. The difference between the sample and my case is that I'm creating a new FuncViewModel object instead of just new. What should be done to correct the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code

```html
 //Unassigned
            editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions = editSecRoleViewModel.UnassignedFunctions.SelectMany( 
                uf => globalFunctions.Where(gf => uf.FuncCode== gf.FuncCode).DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (uf, gf) => new FuncViewModel()
                    {
                        Descrip = uf.Descrip,
                        FuncCode = uf.FuncCode,
                        Grouping = uf.Grouping,
                        Progmodule = uf.Progmodule,
                        SubCat = uf.SubCat,
                        GrantPerm = (byte)( ((gf==null)?1:gf.GrantPerm) | uf.GrantPerm) ,
                        DefaultGrantPerm = ((gf == null) ? (byte)1 : gf.GrantPerm)
                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Descrip);
```