# How to keep original values with join operator?

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-entities

I got two lists that I need to join to set a value between them.
The first list is `companytaxesnumber` and the second is `ordertaxes`.
Both of them got a `TaxId` which is used to join them.

Here the code about that :

```
destination.OrderTaxes = destination.OrderTaxes.
            Join(src.companytaxesnumber, vModel => vModel.TaxId, source => source.TaxId, (dest, source) =>
            {
                  dest.LegalNumber = source.LegalNumber; return dest;
            }).ToList();
```

My problem is if `companytaxesnumber` have less data then `ordertaxes` (for any reason), the join operator will return a result
with the count of `companytaxesnumber` and will lost the other data of `ordertaxes` that it has not been able to join.

Did you know how can I make sure I got the complete `ordertaxes` list even if some data has not been join with `companytaxesnumber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you can accomplish your task with:

```
var result = from o in destination.OrderTaxes
             join d in src.companytaxesnumber on o.TaxId equals d.TaxId into temp
             from p in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { /* assign the fields appropriately */ };
```

a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will allow you to retain all elements on the first collection regardless of whether it has any correlated elements in the second collection.

Comment: Is there any equivalent with the same syntax of the code I showed?

Comment: you can but it gets a little bit messy than it's using query syntax. see [**How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)