# Convert three tables PostgreSQL query to Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

How can I convert next SQL query to Entity Framework

```
SELECT 
  customers."CustomerId",
  customers."CustomerName",
  "Orders"."OrderId",
  "Orders"."Description",
  "Orders"."CustomerId",
  "OrderDetails"."OrderDetailId",
  "OrderDetails"."Article",
  "OrderDetails"."OrderId"
FROM
  "Orders"
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN customers ON ("Orders"."CustomerId" = customers."CustomerId")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "OrderDetails" ON ("Orders"."OrderId" = "OrderDetails"."OrderId")
```

What I have tried:

```
public List<customers> GetAll() 
{ 
    var custord= _dbContext.customers .Include(x => x.Order) .Include(x => x.OrderDetails) .ToList(); return custord;
    
}
```

**The problem**:
If I have Order without OrderDetail information I can not get all records.

ER Diagram looks like
[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: EF deals with entities and objects, not tables and joins. If you have Order, Customer and `OrderDetail` classes with navigation properties ie `Order.OrderDetails`, `Customer.Orders`, `Order.Customer`, then EF will generate the JOINs when you execute eg `context.Customers.Include(c=>c.Orders).ThenInclude(o=>o.OrderDetails).ToList()`. As long as you follow naming conventions all you have to do is define the DbSet<T> properties

Comment: ORMs like EF or NHibernate try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. If you have to use JOINs, it means something is missing

Comment: What have you tried, and what result did you get versus what result did you expect?  There are a ton of tutorials out there on how to query using EF. [Please show your research and attempts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: public List<customers> GetAll()
{
   
    var custord=  _dbContext.customers
        .Include(x => x.Order)
        .Include(x => x.OrderDetails)
        .ToList();

    return custord;
}

If I have Order without OrderDetail information I can not get all records

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552859/how-can-i-implement-a-left-outer-join-in-linq-using-lambda-syntax-on-entity-fram) for how to do a left join

Comment: @BoS, it can be if you defined Required navigation property when it is not, or data in database is broken.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution, thanks all:

```
var item = (
from Order in _dbContext.Orders
join Customer in _dbContext.Customers on Order.CustomerId equals Customer.CustomerId
join OrderDetail in _dbContext.OrderDetails on Order.OrderId equals OrderDetail.OrderId
select new
{
    CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId,
    CustomerName = Customer.CustomerName,
    OrderId = Order.OrderId,
    Description = Order.Description,
    OrderDetailId = OrderDetail.OrderDetailId,
    Article = OrderDetail.Article,

}).ToList();
```