# LINQ Lambda query with JOIN and WHERE 'not in'

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda, where-clause

I am trying to create a Lambda query of my database searching for students that have taken classes but have not paid for their classes.  I am passing in a StudentID (datatype string) and searching the CLASS and PAYMENT tables looking for COUNT of the records in the CLASS table that do NOT have a matching record in the PAYMENT table.

CLASS table has a StudentID field and a ClassID field (datatype GUID)
PAYMENT table has a ClassID field (datatype GUID).

My new to LINQ and Lambda and haven't gotten very far as I keep getting syntax errors.  Help would be sincerely appreciated.

```
int unPaidClasses =
                db.CLASS
                .Join(db.PAYMENT,
                class => class.ClassID,
                pay => pay.ClassId,
                (class, pay) => new { CLASS = class, PAYMENT = payment })
                .Where(x =>
```

Comment: You might be getting syntax errors because `class` is a keyword.

Comment: `as I keep getting syntax errors.` What are the syntax errors?

Comment: Using keywords is bad practice but if you really must do it then precede it with the @ symbol ```@class```.  However; I suggest using a different name in your code that makes sense; i.e. ```payClass``` possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work (making assumptions on which properties are available):

```
var unpaidClasses = db.CLASS.Where(cls => 
    cls.StudentID == studentID 
    && !db.PAYMENT.Any(pmt => 
        pmt.StudentID == studenID 
        && pmt.ClassID = cls.ClassID));
```

That should give you an `IQueryable<CLASS>` for anything without any matching payment records, assuming that payments are also associated with students.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few pointers to help you resolve the issue independently:

- `class` is a reserved word. Do not use it to name variables. Use `cls` or some other valid identifier instead.
- You need left `Join`, because you are looking for classes where the payment record is missing. [Here is how it is done using fluent syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584840/335858); note `DefaultIfEmpty()` call.
- `Where` condition should check that `PAYMENT` is `null`.
- Do not use all-caps for property names (`Class` instead of `CLASS`, `Payment` instead of `PAYMENT`). See [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).