# Add Properties from Different Lists on Matching ID

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm pulling data from two sources with a common ID. One set of data has metadata while the other does not. I want to end up with one list that has the common information.

```
public class Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MetaInfo1 { get; set; }
    public string MetaInfo2 { get; set; }

}
List<Record> doc = new List<Record>(); //About 100k items, MetaInfo is null

List<Record> docWithMeta = new List<Record>(); //About 50k items, Name and Title Null
```

I've tried using `Join`, but the 2nd dataset doesn't always have a matching ID and the end result is a List that only contains items that had a match. It's okay that the end result should have records with missing metadata.

```
var joint = doc.Join(docWithMeta,
            a => a.Id,
            b => b.Id,
            (a, b) => new Record
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                Title = a.Title,                        
                MetaInfo1 = b.MetaInfo1,
                MetaInfo2 = b.MetaInfo2,
            }).ToList();
```

I tried using nested `foreach` loops, to find a match and add the properties to a new list, which works, but the code was very slow.

```
List<Record> newDoc = new List<Record>();

foreach (Record rec in doc)
{
   foreach (Record recMeta in docWithMeta)
   {
      if (rec.Id == recMeta.Id)
      {
         rec.MetaInfo1 = recMeta.MetaInfo1;
         rec.MetaInfo1 = recMeta.MetaInfo1;
      }
   }
   newDoc.Add(rec);
}
```

I also tried using `GroupJoin`, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it and I keep getting a null exception.

```
var results = doc.GroupJoin(docWithMeta,
              a => a.Id,
              b => b.Id,
              (a, result) => new Record
              { 
                 Id = a.Id,
                 MetaInfo1 = result.FirstOrDefault().MetaInfo1 //null exception here
              }).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Using some of the suggestions below I got an adequately performing method that works.

```
var results = doc.GroupJoin(docWithMeta,
           a => a.Id,
           b => b.Id,
           (a, result) => new 
           { 
             Foo = f,
             Bar = result }      
           }).SelectMany(
              x => x.Bar.DefaultIfEmpty(),
              (x, y) => new Record
              {
                 Id = x.Foo.Id,
                 Name = x.Foo.Name,
                 MetaInfo1 = y == null ? null : y.MetaInfo1,
                 MetaInfo2 = y == null ? null : y.MetaInfo2
              }).ToList();
```

I kept getting a NullReferenceException whenever the dataset with metadata didn't have an Id that matched the first data set. I just used a ternary operator to check for `null`. There must be a better way.

Comment: I think this example will help - The key bit is the DefaultOrEmpty() call - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods

Comment: Use left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Thank's Sam. Using your example helped me move in the right direction, but I kept getting a NullReferrenceException whenever there wasn't a matching record in the metadata set.

Answer (score 1):

I can not check this code now, but i think it must be work

```
doc.GroupJoin(
      docWithMeta,
      a => a.Id,
      b => b.Id,
      (a, b) => new { doc = a, meta = b })
  .SelectMany(
      ab => ab.docWithMeta.DefaultIfEmpty(),
      (x, y) => new { doc = x.doc, meta = y })
  .Select(s => new
  {
      Id = s.doc.Id,
      Name = s.doc.Name,
      Title = s.doc.Title,                        
      MetaInfo1 = s.meta?.MetaInfo1 == null ? "" : s.meta?.MetaInfo1,
      MetaInfo2 = s.meta?.MetaInfo2 == null ? "" : s.meta?.MetaInfo2,  
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: I still get a nullreferenceexception whenever there isn't a matching record in the metadata set.

Comment: where specifically you getting this exception?

Comment: "MetaInfo1 = s.meta.MetaInfo1" meta comes in null and it throws an exception

Comment: ok, i changed solution, i think it's have to solve your problem