# How do you perform a left outer join with a where clause using linq lambda extension methods

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, left-join, where-clause

I have the following code in sql and I want to make the linq lambda query. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Idea i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IdeaCollaborator ic
        ON ic.Idea_Id = i.Id
WHERE i.Submitter_Id = 'Peter'
      OR ic.User_Id = 'Peter';
```

I take a reference to [How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods)

and get

```
db.Ideas
 .GroupJoin(
   db.IdeaCollaborators,
   i => i.Id,
   ic => ic.Idea_Id,
   (x, y) => new { Ideas = x, IdeaCollaborators = y })
 .SelectMany(
   x => x.IdeaCollaborators.DefaultIfEmpty(),
   (x, y) => new
   { x.Ideas.Id, x.Ideas.IdeaStatus_Id, y.User_Id}
 )
```

But I got stuck

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the use of .FirstOrDefault() in the relation of the where, because in the relation the FirstOrDefault take the same item that we are going to take from the select so works for the where clause

```
db.Ideas
 .GroupJoin(
  db.IdeaCollaborators,
  i => i.Id,
  ic => ic.Idea_Id,
  (x, y) => new { Ideas = x, IdeaCollaborators = y })
 .Where(gj => gj.Ideas.Submitter_Id == "Peter" | gj.IdeaCollaborators.FirstOrDefault().User_Id == "Peter")
 .SelectMany(
  x => x.IdeaCollaborators.DefaultIfEmpty(),
  (x, y) => new
  { x.Ideas.Id, x.Ideas.IdeaStatus_Id, y.User_Id })
);
```