# NullReferenceException when trying to implement LEFT JOIN with Linq Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, left-join

The idea is to perform a `LEFT JOIN` using LINQ's lambda notation. The situation is as follows:

I have a list `dbList` with entries `(DateTime) UploadTimestamp`, `(int) EntityId`, and `(string) FileName`, generated by the following code:

```cs
var dbList = Db.Pages.Where(s => s.IsCurrent == true).
      Join(Db.Files, // (inner) table to join
           o => o.FileId, //outerKeySelector 
           i => i.Id,     //innerKeySelector
           (o, res) => new // resultSelector 
            { UploadTimestamp = o.SubmissionDate, 
              o.EntityId, 
              res.FileName
            });
```

Then I have another list with fields `(String) FullPath`, `(String) FileName`, `(DateTime) LastModified`. The code reads

```
var rootLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXPORT-FILE-LOCATION"];
string[] entries = Directory.GetFiles(rootLocation, "*.csv");
var fileList = entries.Select(x => new {
     FullPath = x,
     FileName = Path.GetFileName(x),
     LastModified = File.GetLastWriteTime(x)
});
```

The two tables should be connected by `FileName` in order to compare the two timestamps. In SQL I would write

```sql
SELECT left.*, right.* FROM fileList as left
LEFT JOIN dbList as right ON left.FileName = right.FileName
WHERE left.LastModified > right.UploadTimestamp OR right.FileName is NULL
```

But how do I do that that with LINQ lambda notation? For a start, I tried without the `WHERE` condition, inspired by [How do you perform a left outer join using linq extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/)

```cs
var comboList = fileList.GroupJoin( // outer sequence
        dbList,  // inner sequence
        outerTab => outerTab.FileName, // outerKeySelector
        innerTab => innerTab.FileName, // innerKeySelector
        (x, y) => new { Links = x, Rechts = y }).
     SelectMany( x => x.Rechts.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, y) => new { 
          y.FileName, DatabaseTable = y.EntityId,
          x.Links.FullPath, y.UploadTimestamp,
          x.Links.LastModified
          // Outdated = DateTime.Compare(y.UploadTimestamp, x.outerTab.LastModified) > 0 ? false : true
});
```

This does not work and I am currently receiving as error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'y was null.

I have a clue (only) what that means. **What is the correct way to implement my SQL statement above in LINQ lambda notation?** Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error it appears y was null.

Make sure y is not null before dereferencing.

```
SelectMany( x => x.Rechts.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (x, y) => new { 
      Filename = y?.FileName, 
      DatabaseTable = y?.EntityId,
      x.Links.FullPath, 
      UploadTimestamp = y?.UploadTimestamp,
      x.Links.LastModified
```

This does mean the resulting objects can have `FileName`, `DatabaseTable` and `UploadTimestamp` as null, so consumers of that should still check for nulls on those before using them as well.

Comment: Simple solution to just add some clever question marks, but it saved my day!